# Project Target Framework Not Installed 4.7.1 and 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I don't understand why I'm getting this error after downloading the frameworks 4.7.1 and 4.7.2 developer packs [VS Frameworks](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks)

It even gives me the option to start a new project with these frameworks, so I do not understand??

Error

[image: Error]

Frameworks

[image: Frameworks]

Version

[image]

Comment: I don't see `4.7` in your installed list. You have everything _but_ that installed.

Comment: It looks like you have the targeting packs installed, but do you have the .NET frameworks installed? The targeting packs and frameworks are two different things. Also make sure you have the 4.7 targeting pack installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says you are targeting version 4.7.  Your other screen captures show that you have versions 4.7.1 and 4.7.2 installed.  Try changing your version 4.7 reference to version 4.7.1 or 4.7.2.

This is normally done with the dropdown show in your Frameworks link.  If that isn't working, you can manually check the project file.  Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and choose `Unload Project`.  Right-click the project again and choose `Edit myproject.csproj`.  Near the top, you should see a line like this:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

If that just says 4.7, then update it.  Save and close the .csproj file.  Right-click the project again, and choose `Reload Project`

Comment: Ah, okay I see, I am fairly new to VS and I thought that the two frameworks I downloaded would be backwards compatible with 4.7.  I have installed 4.7 and now I am not getting the error message above!  I think I will install all of them from 4.6.1 for piece of mind.

Comment: Thanks - this solved my problem too. Not sure why 4.7 disappeared, it was installed. I think one of the VS updates must have removed it somehow, it is still showing under the VS Installation as installed...